# R How to produce complex table of number with subscripts and superscripts

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have taken the image below from a well known racing website. They have a SQL database. Each row contains a name with various numbers corresponding to past performance with other indicators like position, distance, going represented in the subscripts and superscripts on the left of the name.

If i have a similar database, accessing from R - what is the easiest way to display the data in a similar box-like, table-like display with superscripts and subscripts? Can this be done using Latex? Are there better packages that would enable me to produce something similar?

Many thanks,

[image]

Comment: I would go for R Sweave and LaTeX to produce such a tables into PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

You could reproduce tables by hand with http://www.tablesgenerator.com/. 
Note that this process is time consuming. It is alright to use a single time, but if you need to reproduce on a regular basis, maybe there is something automatic out there?

Or you could actually program it yourself. Once you know how tables are set up with http://www.tablesgenerator.com/, it seems easy to me to format database exported data to latex code.

Superscript text can be added for each cell seperately with:
`This is now \textsuperscript{superscripted}`

By adding a package (`\usepackage{fixltx2e}`) subscript can be used with:
`This is now \textsubscript{subscripted}`.

Comment: Tablegenerator is great! Thanks for the tip - can the latex code create there just be pasted straight into sweave and it pretty much works?

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not have experience with Sweave (nor R).